# Differential of exponential

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\exp_x:U_x\subset T_xM\to O_x\subset M$ denote the exponential map at $x$ such that it is a diffeomorphism between $U_x$ and $O_x$. Define $U:=\cup_xU_x\subset TM$ and $O:=\cup_x O_x\subset M$, and let $\exp:U\to O$ be the exponential map defined as $\exp(v)=\exp_x(v)$ if $v\in U_x$.

> Is there a way to compute or differentiating $\exp$ with respect to $x$?

Even a simple example in a simple space ($S^2$ for instance) is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "compute".

Let me work out your example of $S^2 = \{(a, b, c)\in\mathbb{R}^3:a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1\}$ and the point $x = (1, 0, 0)$.

The tangent space of $S^2$ at $x$ is the plane orthogonal to the $a$-axis, or simply the plane $a = 0$. Thus a tangent vector is of the form $(0, r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$.

The geodesics on $S^2$ are the great circles. So imagin you are an ant standing on $S^2$ at the point $x$, and you want to go in the direction of $(0, r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, then you are actually moving along the great circle $\{(\cos\varphi, \sin\varphi\cos\theta, \sin\varphi\sin\theta): \varphi\in[0, 2\pi)\}$. Drawing a picture is recommended here.

Hence if you go along that geodesic for the same length of your tangent vector $(0, r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, which is $r$, then you arrive at $(\cos r, \sin r\cos\theta, \sin r\sin\theta)$.

This means that $\exp_x(0, r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta) = (\cos r, \sin r\cos\theta, \sin r\sin\theta)$.

As you can see, even for such a simple example, the explicit formula is rather complicated. Usually people don't compute things so explicitly, but use certain properties to characterize the result.

---

After posting the answer, I realized that I didn't mention anything about differentiating $\exp$. But this is almost tautologically equal to the identity map on $T_xM$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your example. In fact my question was not so clear.  I said "compute" because I am trying to give a meaning to the expression $D(\varphi\circ s)$ where $\varphi\in C^\infty(M)$ and $s(x)=\exp_x(\zeta(x))$ for a vector field $\zeta\in\mathscr{X}(M)$, where $M=S^2$.

Comment: This consists of several steps. You have the map $s:M\rightarrow M$ which is taking exponential on $\zeta(x)$, and then composing it with $\varphi$ gives a function $\varphi\circ s:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Finally differentiating the function (on any point $x$) and you get a linear map from $T_xM$ to $\mathbb{R}$ for every $x$.

Comment: Yes exactly, when I apply the classical chain rule I get stuck at the term $D(\exp_x(\zeta(x)))$ since $\exp$ varies also in $x$.

Comment: Or should I just write $D\exp$ without caring about the $x$?

Comment: Whenever you take differential, you should fix a point $x$, and the differential will just happen in an infinitesimal neighborhood of that $x$. Sometimes people write things like $TM$, pretending that it is "one space". This is slightly confusing, because for different points $x, x'$, the spaces $T_xM$ and $T_{x'}M$ don't have anything to do with each other. Here it's the same, the $\exp_x$ and $\exp_{x'}$ are totally unrelated. Hope this clarifies your problem?

Comment: The problem actually already appears in the statement of your question, where you wrote $\cup_xU_x$ $\cup_xO_x$, etc. These are actually not unions, but just collections of spaces indexed by $x$. Sometimes people write disjoint unions for these.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.